# How do i recieve a datagram packet

Tags: java, datagram

This is the Client frame. In it is the line "hello server". I want to to have "hello server" show up in the server frame. The code  i have so far is what i have managed to remember from my text book. I cant remember the rest.

```
package datagrams;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {


    public Client() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @Override
    public void run(){

        DatagramSocket socket = null;
        DatagramPacket recvPacket, sendPacket;
        this.setVisible(true);
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress  hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            String userString = "hello server";
            byte sendbuf[] = userString.getBytes();
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendbuf, sendbuf.length, hostAddress, 1167);
            socket.send(sendPacket);
            recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(new byte[512], 512);
            socket.receive(recvPacket);


        catch(Exception ioe){


        }
        socket.close();

            }
```

and the server frame

```
package datagrams;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {

    static int  PORT = 7070;

    public Server() {
        initComponents();

    }

    @Override public void run(){
        DatagramSocket socket = null;
        DatagramPacket recvPacket, sendPacket;
        this.setVisible(true);
        try{
            socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
            while (socket != null){
                recvPacket = new DatagramPacket(new byte[512], 512);
                socket.receive(recvPacket);
                sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(recvPacket.getData(), recvPacket.getLength(), recvPacket.getAddress(), recvPacket.getPort());
                socket.send(sendPacket);
            }

        }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    socket.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In client program you have used port 1167... But in the server you are trying to receive from the port 7070....So make both the port same(say 7070) to receive the message....

Comment: Ok. I changed that. Nothing happens?

Comment: Plz try to write your code to produce output in console first. Then you can go for advanced interface.Bcoz you won't know where the issue is actually.

Comment: I copied your code and edited  to make console driven. It works fine when i make both the ports same. You have to open two console , one to run server and other for client. And one more thing execute the server program first and then client.